# Java MergeSort with Strings

Tags: java, string, recursion, mergesort

My teacher is out this week and she gave us this merge sort code to use. It is written for an int[]array and we are supposed to make one for a String[]array.

Here is her code:

```
public static void mergeSort(int[ ] a, int from, int to)
{  if (from == to) return;
  int mid = (from + to) / 2;
   // sort the first and the second half
  mergeSort(a, from, mid);
  mergeSort(a, mid + 1, to);
  merge(a, from, mid, to);     }// end mergeSort

public static void merge(int[ ] a, int from, int mid, int to)
{  int n = to - from + 1;         // size of the range to be merged
  int[ ] b = new int[n]; // merge both halves into a temporary array b 
  int i1 = from;         // next element to consider in the first range
  int i2 = mid + 1;      // next element to consider in the second range
  int j = 0;             // next open position in b

  // as long as neither i1 nor i2 past the end, move the smaller into b
  while (i1 <= mid && i2 <= to)
  {  if (a[i1] < a[i2])
     {  b[j] = a[i1];
        i1++;          }
     else
     {  b[j] = a[i2];
        i2++;           }
     j++;
  }

  // note that only one of the two while loops below is executed

  // copy any remaining entries of the first half
  while (i1 <= mid)
  {  b[j] = a[i1];
     i1++;
     j++;        }

  // copy any remaining entries of the second half
  while (i2 <= to)
  {  b[j] = a[i2];
     i2++;
     j++;      }

  // copy back from the temporary array
  for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
     a[from + j] = b[j];
}// end merge
```

Now here is my attempt:

```
//merge sort
public static void mergeSort(String[] a, int from, int to)
{  
    if (from == to)
        return;
    int mid = (from + to) / 2;
    // sort the first and the second half
    mergeSort(a, from, mid);
    mergeSort(a, mid + 1, to);
    merge(a, from, mid, to);
}// end mergeSort
//work
public static void merge(String[] a, int from, int mid, int to)
{  
    int n = to - from + 1;       // size of the range to be merged
    String[]b = new String[n];   // merge both halves into a temporary array b 
    int i1 = from;               // next element to consider in the first range
    int i2 = mid + 1;            // next element to consider in the second range
    int j = 0;                   // next open position in b

    // as long as neither i1 nor i2 past the end, move the smaller into b
    while (i1 <= mid && i2 <= to)
    {  
        if (a[i1].compareTo(a[i2]) > 0)
        {  
            b[j] = a[i1];
            i1++;          
        }
        else
        {  
            b[j] = a[i2];
            i2++;           
        }
        j++;
    }

    // note that only one of the two while loops below is executed

    // copy any remaining entries of the first half
    while (i1 <= mid)
    {  
        b[j] = a[i1];
        i1++;
        j++;
    }

    // copy any remaining entries of the second half
    while (i2 <= to)
    {  
        b[j] = a[i2];
        i2++;
        j++;
    }

    // copy back from the temporary array
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        a[from + j] = b[j];
}//end merge
```

I feel like the code she gave us is missing something that she would normally explain to us in class but since she is out I'm lost as to what to do. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What exactly goes wrong when you do this?

Comment: For better help sooner, form a specific question.

Comment: "I feel like the code she gave us is missing something that she would normally explain to us in class but since she is out I'm lost as to what to do" - is that because you are having trouble understanding how Merge Sort works? Or how should we understand this?

Answer (score 0):

Everything works find - only your `compareTo` in `merge` has the wrong direction. Here is a working example

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MergeSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] values = {"foo", "bar", "alice", "bob", "celine", "david"};
        mergeSort(values, 0, values.length - 1);
        System.out.println("Result " + Arrays.toString(values));
    }

    public static void mergeSort(String[] a, int from, int to) {
        if (from == to) {
            return;
        }
        int mid = (from + to) / 2;
        // sort the first and the second half
        mergeSort(a, from, mid);
        mergeSort(a, mid + 1, to);
        merge(a, from, mid, to);
    }// end mergeSort
//work

    public static void merge(String[] a, int from, int mid, int to) {
        int n = to - from + 1;       // size of the range to be merged
        String[] b = new String[n];   // merge both halves into a temporary array b
        int i1 = from;               // next element to consider in the first range
        int i2 = mid + 1;            // next element to consider in the second range
        int j = 0;                   // next open position in b

        // as long as neither i1 nor i2 past the end, move the smaller into b
        while (i1 <= mid && i2 <= to) {
            if (a[i1].compareTo(a[i2]) < 0) {
                b[j] = a[i1];
                i1++;
            } else {
                b[j] = a[i2];
                i2++;
            }
            j++;
        }

        // note that only one of the two while loops below is executed
        // copy any remaining entries of the first half
        while (i1 <= mid) {
            b[j] = a[i1];
            i1++;
            j++;
        }

        // copy any remaining entries of the second half
        while (i2 <= to) {
            b[j] = a[i2];
            i2++;
            j++;
        }

        // copy back from the temporary array
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            a[from + j] = b[j];
        }
    }//end merge

}
```

Comment: Thanks! It is working perfectly now. It's always the little things!